# Create rowspan and editable data in React+Typescript using React table or Any other alternatives?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-table

I am required to make a table according to the provisions above, I have done many ways to be able to make the table above but none of them are suitable, can the experts here provide an alternative in the form of a library or code that can implement the table?
[Table Picture that i want to build here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsCT4.png)
My closest attempt was using the following code, but as you can see. Tables with the same id or number are not combined as in the table image. Even though the existing cells can be edited.

```
import {
  createColumnHelper,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from '@tanstack/react-table';
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem 0;
  overflow : scroll;
  table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
    border-left: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
    border-radius : 12px;
    tr {
      :last-child {
        tr{
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    thead{
      color : white;
      background-color : #036BB0;
    }
    th{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
      border-right: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
      border-left: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
    }
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.3rem;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
      border-right: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
      border-left: 2px solid #D5E4F0;
      z-index: -1;

      input {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .pagination {
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
`
type kualifikasi20 = {
  seri: string;
  '0': number;
  '1': number;
  '2': number;
  '3': number;
  '4': number;
  '5': number;
  '6': number;
  '7': number;
  '8': number;
  '9': number;
  '10': number;
  total: number;
  hasil: boolean;
};
const defaultData: kualifikasi20[] = [
  {
    seri: '1',
    '0': 1,
    '1': 1,
    '2': 1,
    '3': 1,
    '4': 1,
    '5': 1,
    '6': 1,
    '7': 1,
    '8': 1,
    '9': 1,
    '10': 1,
    total: 11,
    hasil: false,
  },
  {
    seri: '1',
    '0': 1,
    '1': 1,
    '2': 1,
    '3': 1,
    '4': 1,
    '5': 1,
    '6': 1,
    '7': 1,
    '8': 1,
    '9': 1,
    '10': 1,
    total: 11,
    hasil: false,
  },
];

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<kualifikasi20>();

const EditableCell = ({ getValue, row, column, table }: any) => {
  const initialValue = getValue();
  const columnMeta = column.columnDef.meta;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);
  const onBlur = () => {
    table.options.meta?.updateData(row.index, column.id, value);
  };
  return columnMeta?.type === 'number' ? (
    <input className='w-[30px] text-center'
      min={0}
      max={10}
      type="number"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  ) : (
    <input className='w-[30px] text-center'
      type={columnMeta?.type || "text"}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  );
}

const columns = [
  columnHelper.group({
    id: 'seri',
    header: () => <span>Seri</span>,
    // footer: props => props.column.id,
    columns: [
      columnHelper.accessor('seri', {
        id: 'seri',
        header: () => <span>id</span>,
      }),
    ]
  }),
  columnHelper.group({
    id: 'nilaiPerkenaan',
    header: () => <span>Nilai Perkenaan</span>,
    // footer: props => props.column.id,
    columns: [
      columnHelper.accessor('0', {
        id: '0',
        header: () => <span>0</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('1', {
        id: '1',
        header: () => <span>1</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('2', {
        id: '2',
        header: () => <span>2</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('3', {
        id: '3',
        header: () => <span>3</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('4', {
        id: '4',
        header: () => <span>1</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('5', {
        id: '5',
        header: () => <span>5</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('6', {
        id: '6',
        header: () => <span>6</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('7', {
        id: '7',
        header: () => <span>7</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('8', {
        id: '8',
        header: () => <span>8</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('9', {
        id: '9',
        header: () => <span>9</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
      columnHelper.accessor('10', {
        id: '10',
        header: () => <span>10</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'number',
        }
      }),
    ],
  }),
  columnHelper.group({
    id: 'total',
    header: () => <span>Result</span>,
    // footer: props => props.column.id,
    columns: [
      columnHelper.accessor('total', {
        id: 'total',
        header: () => <span>Results Total</span>,
      }),
    ]
  }),
  columnHelper.group({
    id: 'hasil',
    header: () => <span>Checkbox</span>,
    // footer: props => props.column.id,
    columns: [
      columnHelper.accessor('hasil', {
        id: 'hasil',
        header: () => <span>Checkbox</span>,
        cell: EditableCell,
        meta: {
          type: 'checkbox',
        }
      }),
    ]
  }),
]

const Kualifikasi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => [...defaultData])
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    meta: {
      updateData: ({ rowIndex, columnId, value }: any) => {
        setData((old) =>
          old.map((row, index) => {
            if (index === rowIndex) {
              return {
                ...old[rowIndex],
                [columnId]: value,
              };
            }
            return row;
          })
        );
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <Styles>
      <table>
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                      header.column.columnDef.header,
                      header.getContext()
                    )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (

            <tr key={row.id}>
              {/* {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                console.log(cell.row.original.seri)
                <p>{cell}</p>
              ))} */}
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell, row) => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
          {/* {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {cell.id}
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))} */}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default Kualifikasi
```

Comment: If you can you reduce your code to a minimum (e.g. with just one table row), that will increase the chance of getting an answer.